# Calculating the Dottie number using an infinite series

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, special-functions, summation

The Dottie number is the solution to the equation

$\cos(x) = x$

It is approximately equal to $0.739085133215160641655312.$

This number can be expressed analytically in the following form (see [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46934/what-is-the-solution-of-cosx-x)):

$\displaystyle D = 2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{J_{4n+1}(4n+1)}{4n+1} - \frac{J_{4n+3}(4n+3)}{4n+3}\right) = 2\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)$

Trying to evaluate the infinite series above with `NSum` takes a lot of time, and gives numerical results for small finite upper bounds of summation.
For example:

```
2*NSum[BesselJ[4*n + 1, 4*n + 1]/(4*n + 1) - 
   BesselJ[4*n + 3, 4*n + 3]/(4*n + 3), {n, 0, 2100}]
```

The result found is `0.739027` or

$\displaystyle 2\sum_{n=0}^{2100} f(n) = 0.739027...$

For bigger upper bounds of summation, one gets error messages.

Is there a way to better calculate or evaluate numerically the series with *Mathematica*?

Comment: If possible I want an answer about how to specifically calculate the value of the series mentioned in the question.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: `x /. First[Solve[Cos[x] == x && 0 < x < 1, x]]` gives a usable `Root[]` expression for the Dottie number, which might be more convenient than trying to sum your series.

Answer (score 5):

To specify the desired accuracy.

```
s = NestWhile[Cos, 0, (Abs[#2 - #1] > 10^-500) &, 2];
N[s, 500]
```

Comment: `FixedPoint[Cos, 1``20, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-500 &)]` to avoid error messages on `N::meprec`.

Answer (score 5):

If you insist on using the Bessel function summation, you could sum the exact terms for $n=0,1,2,\ldots,N$ and then use the series expansion

$$
J_n(n) =
\frac{\Gamma(\frac13)}{2^{2/3}\cdot 3^{1/6} \cdot \pi}n^{-1/3}
- \frac{1}{35\cdot 6^{1/3}\cdot\Gamma(\frac13)}n^{-5/3}
- \frac{\Gamma(\frac13)}{225 \cdot 2^{2/3}\cdot 3^{1/6}\cdot \pi}n^{-7/3}
+\mathcal{O}(n^{-11/3})
$$

to approximately sum the remaining terms $n=N+1,N+2,\ldots$ all the way to infinity:

```
f[n_] = BesselJ[n, n]/n;
fa[n_] = (Gamma[1/3]/(2^(2/3)*3^(1/6)*π)*n^(-1/3)
          - 1/(35*6^(1/3)*Gamma[1/3])*n^(-5/3)
          - Gamma[1/3]/(225*2^(2/3)*3^(1/6)*π)*n^(-7/3))/n;

With[{nn = 10},
  X = 2*Sum[f[4n+1]-f[4n+3], {n, 0, nn}] +
      2*Sum[fa[4n+1]-fa[4n+3], {n, nn+1, ∞}]] // N
(* 0.739085 *)
Cos[X] - X // N
(* 1.82089*10^-11 *)
```

In this way you get a much faster convergence in $N$. Using a higher-order series expansion would make it even faster; see [math.SE #3162888](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3162888) for a formula for the higher-order terms.

Comment: If I may ask, how did you find this splendid expansion ?

Answer (score 5):

Amplifying @JM's comment, you can use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) to get an exact expression for the Dottie number:

```
dottie = x /. First @ Solve[Cos[x]==x, x, Reals]
```

> Root[{-Cos[#1] + #1 &, 0.73908513321516064166}]

This expression is exact, and can be numericized to any desired precision, e.g.:

```
N[dottie, 200]
```

> 0.73908513321516064165531208767387340401341175890075746496568063577328465488354759459937610693176653184980124664398716302771490369130842031578044057462077868852490389153928943884509523480133563127677223

Answer (score 4):

Another way to solve for the number $D$ numerically is to iterate the function:

```
x[n_] := x[n] = Cos[x[n - 1]];
x[0] = 1;
```

For example:

```
N[x[500], 200]
```

shows this to 200 decimal places. You can get bounds on the accuracy of the approximation by looking at terms like

```
N[x[3000], 1000] - N[x[5000], 1000]
```

which shows that the error is less than about 10^-500.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **very impractical** way to evaluate the Dottie number. Starting from the given [Kapteyn series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KapteynSeries.html) for the Dottie number in the OP, plug in [an integral representation of the Bessel function of the first kind](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/07/01/01/0006/), and interchange summation and integration. That is, consider the integral

$$\small D=\frac2{\pi}\int_0^\pi\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sin((4n+1)u)\sin((4n+1)\sin u)}{4n+1}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sin((4n+3)u)\sin((4n+3)\sin u)}{4n+3}\right)\mathrm du$$

To evaluate the resulting Fourier series, use the [trigonometric product (Werner) formulae](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html), which allows an expression in terms of the functions

$$\begin{align*}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{4n+1}}{4n+1}&=z\; {}_2 F_1\left({{\frac14,1}\atop{\frac54}}\middle|z^4\right)\\\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{4n+3}}{4n+3}&=\frac{z^3}{3}{}_2 F_1\left({{\frac34,1}\atop{\frac74}}\middle|z^4\right)\end{align*}$$

with arguments $z=\exp(\pm i(u\pm\sin u))$. Performing the (tedious!) algebra with some help from *Mathematica*, we finally obtain

```
cc1 = u /. First[Solve[u - Sin[u] == π/2, u, Reals]];
cc2 = u /. First[Solve[u + Sin[u] == π/2, u, Reals]];

NIntegrate[With[{z = Exp[I (u - Sin[u])]}, 
                z Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1, 5/4, z^4] + 
                Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1, 5/4, z^-4]/z - 
                z^3/3 Hypergeometric2F1[3/4, 1, 7/4, z^4] - 
                Hypergeometric2F1[3/4, 1, 7/4, z^-4]/(3 z^3)] - 
           With[{z = Exp[I (u + Sin[u])]}, 
                z Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1, 5/4, z^4] + 
                Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1, 5/4, z^-4]/z - 
                z^3/3 Hypergeometric2F1[3/4, 1, 7/4, z^4] - 
                Hypergeometric2F1[3/4, 1, 7/4, z^-4]/(3 z^3)],
           {u, 0, cc2, cc1, π}, WorkingPrecision -> 35]/(2 π)
   0.73908513321516064165531208767387339
```

where we needed to compute the constants `cc1` and `cc2` to cope with the branch cut behavior of the hypergeometric function ${}_2 F_1$, which messes with the numerical integration.

---

As Roman astutely noted in his comment,

```
z Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1, 5/4, z^4] + 
Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1, 5/4, z^-4]/z - 
z^3/3 Hypergeometric2F1[3/4, 1, 7/4, z^4] - 
Hypergeometric2F1[3/4, 1, 7/4, z^-4]/(3 z^3) // FunctionExpand // Simplify
   ArcCot[z] + ArcTan[z]
```

and the integrand can thus be simplified to a piecewise constant function, such that Dottie's number can just be expressed as `(cc1 - cc2)/2`.

Comment: I assume you realize that the method and effort to calculate `cc1` and `cc2` is identical to calculating the Dottie number directly with @CarlWoll's method.

Comment: Exactly why "very impractical" is in the first sentence.

Comment: The hypergeometrics can be simplified dramatically to `ArcCot[z] + ArcTan[z]`, so that for $u\in (0,cc_2)$ the integrand is zero, for $u\in (cc_2,cc_1)$ it is $\pi$, and for $u\in (cc_1,\pi)$ it is zero again; with these, the integral becomes simply $D=(cc_1-cc_2)/2$. So at the end only the branch cuts of the hypergeometric integral remain and determine $D$.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I didn't even think to simplify the hypergeometrics at once. At the very least, that verifies the correctness of the Kapteyn series in  the OP.